# Why is it allowed for a list to append itself?

Tags: python, list, recursion

I noticed by accident that in Python you can write something like the following:

```py
l = list()
for i in range(5):
  l.append(l)
```

If I print out what l is it looks like this:

```
[[...], [...], [...], [...], [...]]
```

And now I can do things like:

```
l[0][0][0][0]...[0]
```

which will return still the exact same list.

The error I had made in my code was not detected by my linter and so might have been difficult to spot. So my question is: why is it allowed for a list to append itself? What use can you make of it?

If it's not useful it should probably be disallowed.

Comment: Why should it be *disallowed*? That would add some overhead to the `.append` operation, especially if you need to avoid things like `x = []; y = [1,2, x]; x.append(y)`.

Comment: I see, that's a good point for not "disallowing" it. However, is there any use to actually allowing it (which is my original interrogation)?

Comment: I can't think of any good reason, and it creates a reference cycle, so I would probably avoid that approach, but again, in Python, generally you have a philosophy of "if there is no good reason to disallow it then don't, especially if it will significantly affect performance".

Comment: The reason for allowing it is to avoid cluttering the semantics of a language with special cases. Which is easier to understand: "Any object can be added to a list" or "Any object can be added to a list, unless the object *is* the list or an object which contains, directly or indirectly, a reference to that list"?

Comment: This is loosely related to typing, though. Your `l` was probably supposed to be a list of, say, `int` values. If you had written `l : List[int] = list()`, then a tool like `mypy` could have caught the attempt to append something other than an `int` to `l`.

Comment: Ok it makes sense why it is allowed. I am still interested in what use it can have but I guess it's too broad of a question. 
If any of you want to write the comments as an answer I will approve it.
@juanpa.arrivillaga I don't think this is a duplicate of the question "can it be done" since I know it can, I am wondering why.

Comment: @chepner well in my case it was a list of lists, so not really but I see your point in the general case.

Comment: @ZaccharieRamzi that question also asks "why is it allowed", it's just not in the title but in the body of the question. But feel free to vote to re-open, others may agree with you.

Comment: I will since in the answer of the other question mentioned that there is no use in general, but the reasons it's not disallowed are not apparent (except in one comment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your criteria for not allowing a list in a list is that it isn't useful. But it's hard to *prove* that's not true. Maybe nobody knows *yet* a use, but that doesn't someone won't in the future. In the meantime, there is added cost to the language both in terms of explaining what exceptions there are to adding an object to a list, and in implementing those exceptions.

If you could prove that it is *harmful* to allow adding a list to itself, then you would have a stronger case for making that change to the language. But "I accidentally typed the wrong variable name" is not a strong argument for harm.

Answer (score 1):

Why is it allowed for list to append to itself?  Remember that in python, everything is a reference. A list is just a sequence of references to objects.  Since a list is an object, it can be referenced by another list.  When a list references an object, its not like that object is actually contained within the list now, its just that a single element of the sequence is now a reference to that object.  Though circular references are sometimes bad, they are sometimes useful, and nothing has actually been broken here. Remember, a list containing itself is actually just a list that has a reference to itself.

Answer (score -1):

Why is it allowed for a list to append itself?

Your assumption that it's an error and should not be allowed is incorrect. It's up to us as engineers to decide if it's a good fit for the situation we have or not. I'll turn this question around, why do you think it should be disallowed?

What use can you make of it?

Adding arrays to arrays is actually pretty common. I could imagine a situation where you have to start with 5 identical arrays, perform different calculations on each one, then compare the results. This would be a way to accomplish that.

Comment: Your use case is adding a list to another *different* list, not a list to *itself*.

Comment: These are *not arrays* these are *lists* and as pointed out by chepner, the OP is not talking about adding different lists to a list, but a list that contains itself.